# Angular chaining AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise

I have to do 2 AJAX calls. Second one depends on the first call result. Right now I do it like this:

```
Service.getA(car).then(function(carInfo) {
    if (carInfo.success) {
        Service.getB(carInfo.number).then(function(holderInfo) {
            console.log(holderInfo);
        });
    }
});
```

Service:

```
getA: function(car) {
    return Server.execute({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'a/a',
        params: {
            car: car
        },
    }).then(function (carInfo) {
        return carInfo;
    });
},
```

`getB` method is analogous - just another URL and another parameters. I am learning angular and want to implement this code using promises and defers (google suggest that code will be more beautoful). How can I do that?

Comment: You already are, `.then` is a promise method

Comment: I though to do something like this: https://www.jonathanfielding.com/combining-promises-angular/ But I do not understand how to pass parameters.

Comment: @Bob: you can't combine them like that, because the second call requires a variable returned from the first call. `$q.all...` exacutes both calls at the same time, so you can't pass any data to the second one. Basically, the way you're doing it is the way to go.

Comment: You can do something like that when the requests arent dependent on a previous request. The author of that page is doing requests that arent dependent on another one, you on the other hand are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've done it is typically how you chain ajax calls though you can simplify this a bit:

```
  Service.getA(car).then(function(carInfo) {
     Service.getB(carInfo.number).then(function(holderInfo) {
        console.log(holderInfo);
     });
  });
```

For errors have your server return Bad Request 400 and then you can chain the .error() callback instead of determining success based on the `success` property.

As Cerbrus pointed out, `$q.all([promise1, promise2])` executes them in parallel instead of one depending on the other.

Your getA method should just return the promise itself like so:

```
 getA: function(car) {
    return Server.execute({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'a/a',
       params: {
           car: car
       },
    });
  }
```

If you really need to bind the extra callback from within the service you can do this:

```
 getA: function(car) {
    return Server.execute({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'a/a',
        params: {
            car: car
        },
    }).then(function (carInfo) {
        //do something?

    }, function () {
        //handle error?
    });
},
```

Comment: `getA` does not return an `http` promise in the OP's example. So it's not possible to use `success` in the controller.

Comment: @DieterGoetelen, yes it does, .then() calls return a promise object, not that it matters as i believe parliament was talking about the success property of the carInfo object

Comment: Dont use the deferred, .then already returns the promise object thats why you can chain like `.then().then().fail()`

Answer (score 0):

As you've said both are similar except url, parameters I'd go with

```
request : function(url, params) {
    return Server.execute({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        params: params,
    });
},
```

call it

```
Service.request('a/a', param).then(function(carInfo) {
    if (carInfo.success) {
        Service.request('b/b', carInfo.number).then(function(holderInfo) {
            console.log(holderInfo);
        });
    }
});
```